# Spring Boot dont recognice Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am starting with **SpringBoot**, looks great, but I have some questions that I can't understand or find explained in the docs.

I created a new project with the **Web, JPA, Security** and **MySQL** dependencies. When my project is created, I go to create a `@Controller` class. Spring don't find `@RequestMapping` or `ModelAndView` classes.

I guessed that use the Web module of SpringBoot will add all the necessary dependencies to use **SpringMVC** **(I read some examples and none add extra dependencies)** and all work great with MVC.

These are my dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-groovy-templates</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Utils -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
          <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
          <version>22.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Other example, is the **WebMvcConfigurerAdapter** (from spring-mcv) class that I can't resolve:
org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

This class is from, but I don't see Springboot include this dependy:
      org.springframework
      spring-webmvc

Maybe I am wrong and read some post that center all the info in Spring Boot, but don't show manual config in the poms.

**WebApplication** class (Auto Generated):

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class WebApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**ServletInitializer.java class (Auto generated)**

```
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(WebApplication.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you declared a spring boot application class ?

Comment: I use the default class (original post updated) at this moment.

Comment: dependencies look good. have you already peformed a mvn clean install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like my maven local repository is corrupted.
[image]

I was using these libraries in other projects and all works fine. Sorry for the time wasted. Anyway, I let the response for some users with similar problems.